# QListview leaving shadow copies of QStandardItems after reordering

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I created a `QListView` model to simply reorder items and retrieve the text information after the reordering. I have set the `QListView`'s `dragMode` to  `QAbstractItemView::InternalMove`. But instead of moving  an item after the internal dragging and dropping operation, the `QStandardListModel` creates a copy of the item that was moved.

`QStandardListModel` items before reordering (marked in green):

[image: QStandard Model items before reordering]

Below, the "FIPAverageImage" item was dragged and placed bellow the "FIPGaussianFilter" item. The results are normal on `QListView`'s display, but the problem occurs when you retrieve the data from the `QListView`'s model.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <QDropEvent>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QListView>


using namespace std;


DragDropWidget::DragDropWidget(QWidget * parent, std::string strAccessibleName) : QListView(parent) {
    setAccessibleName(QString(strAccessibleName.c_str()));
    setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
    setDragEnabled(true);
    viewport()->setAcceptDrops(true);
    setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::InternalMove);
    setDropIndicatorShown(true);
    setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
    setDragDropOverwriteMode(false);
    setDropIndicatorShown(true);
    setMaximumHeight(400);
}


DragDropWidget::DragDropWidget(){;}
DragDropWidget::~DragDropWidget(){;}


void DragDropWidget::dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *e) {
    //Call the Default behaviour
    QListView::dragMoveEvent(e);

    //Make the QListView to only accept items from another QListViews
    if(this->dragDropMode() == QAbstractItemView::DragDrop){
        if (e->source() != this) {
            e->accept();
        }else {
            e->ignore();
        }
    }else{
        e->accept();
    }
}

void DragDropWidget::dropEvent(QDropEvent* event){
    //Call the Default behaviour
    QListView::dropEvent(event);

    if(this->dragDropMode() == QAbstractItemView::InternalMove){

        ///BUG, this signal emission causes the shadow copies
        emit changeProcessorOrderSignal();
    }
}
```

[image: Shadow copy of the moved item, after reordering]

The following code was used for reading items from the QListView's model.

```
for(int i=0;i<qStandardListModel->count() ; i++)
  listStr = qStandardListModel->model()->index(i,0).data( Qt::DisplayRole ).toString().toStdString();
```

Comment: You must provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with the code that shows I can not reproduce your error.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I was trying to make a simpler example of what Im talking about. It appears that the issue is caused by emitting a signal inside the extended dropEvent() function.